# How can I use this Github library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gradle

I want to use this library in my android studio. 
https://github.com/code-computerlove/FastScrollRecyclerView
I tried importing it as a new module and setting it as a library not application but it gives me this error

> Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set
>   to 'com.codecomputerlove.fastscrollrecyclerviewdemo' in default
>   config.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Removing applicationId variable from the library's build.gradle file should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your github link is not an Android Library, it's an Android Application. You need to convert it to Android Module (Library) or just copy the source code into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the project and drag and drop these files:

> FastScrollRecyclerView.java
>
> FastScrollRecyclerViewInterface.java
>
> FastScrollRecyclerViewItemDecoration.java
>
> MyAdapter.java (optional)
>
> https://github.com/code-computerlove/FastScrollRecyclerView/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/my_text_view.xml (optional)

from this folder
https://github.com/code-computerlove/FastScrollRecyclerView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/codecomputerlove/fastscrollrecyclerviewdemo

into your project

DO NOT FORGET TO READ HOWTO **Readme.md** file

https://github.com/code-computerlove/FastScrollRecyclerView/blob/master/README.md